# How to automatically fill-up an input box base on another input box

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a page that would require the user to input a certain code on the first input box and then automatically the 2nd input box will be filled-up based on what code is input on the 1st box.

```
<input type="text" id="code" name="code">

<input type="text" id="car" name="car" disabled>
```

The following is the list of code with the appropriate car

```
- 1001 - BMW
- 2351 - MAZDA
- 3331 - HONDA
```

So when the user input 1001 on the 1st input box the 2nd input box will show BMW

I know that jquery can be used but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#code").keyup(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $("#car").html(input1[val]);

    });
    var input1 = ["BMW", "MAZDA", "HONDA"];
});
```

Hope someone can enlighten me on the proper use of jquery specifically on this kind of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check below snippet
You have to use array with key , value like object. you can also use Associative Arrays.

And $("#car") is input field so set value of that field using val() method not by html() method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = {1001:"BMW", 2351:"MAZDA", 3331:"HONDA"}
  
  $("#code").keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#car").val(data[val]);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="code" name="code">

    <input type="text" id="car" name="car" disabled>
```

Comment: Wow thank you @Nirali I think this would be the simplest and direct approach to the problem.

Comment: do you know how to save the values in database for the 2nd inputbox?

Comment: you mean when the user input 1001 on the 1st input box the 2nd input box will show BMW at that time store value in db??

Comment: yes at that time 2nd input box will show BMW will save in db

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the value of `<input />`, you should use `val()` with `<input />` in `jQuery`

```js
    var input1 = ["BMW", "MAZDA", "HONDA"];
    $("#code").keyup(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val == '1001'){
          $("#car").val(input1[0]);
        }else if(val =='2351'){
          $("#car").val(input1[1]);
        }else if(val =='3331'){
          $("#car").val(input1[2]);
        }
        

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="code" name="code">

<input type="text" id="car" name="car" disabled>
```

Comment: Thank you @zynkn same as both solutions above this would also solve the problem however I think Nirali has the most direct approach.

Answer (score 1):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhpt599u/)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="code" name="code">

<input type="text" id="car" name="car" disabled>
```

JS:

```
var input1 = [ "BMW","MAZDA","HONDA"];

$("#code").keyup(function(){
$("#car").val("");
var val = $(this).val();
console.log(val);
if(val == 1001)
$("#car").val(input1[0]);
if(val == 2351 )
$("#car").val(input1[1]);
if(val == 3331 )
$("#car").val(input1[2]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Minar Mnr this would also solve the problem however I think Nirali has the most direct approach.

Comment: Welcome. @IanEnriquez .
Yes, completely agree with you.

Comment: do you know how to save the values in database for the 2nd inputbox?